Does gcc support function attribute format for wchar_t?
The GCC C compiler supports a function attribute format for printf.  Here are the official GCC docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-format-function-attribute
Example:
int my_printf(const char *format, ...)
__attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 2)));

GCC will provide an error if this C function is called as:
my_printf("val: %u\n", "abc");

Example error:
error: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Werror=format=]

Does GCC support wchar_t format strings?
Example:
int my_wprintf(const wchar_t *format, ...)
__attribute__ ((__format__ (__wprintf__, 1, 2)));

I cannot get this to work.
Interestingly, I found this in the glibc source code:

https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/1c4cebb84b9e33aea9a90adfadb031d1f1eba927/wcsmbs/wchar.h#L739

extern int wprintf (const wchar_t *__restrict __format, ...)
     /* __attribute__ ((__format__ (__wprintf__, 1, 2))) */;

Notice that __attribute__ is commented-out.
When I compile this code, I do not get an error:
wprintf("val: %u\n", "abc");

Final note: My compiler is a bit weird: It is a Linux-based GCC cross compiler for mingw32.
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 10-win32 20210110


If your target is mingw32 then glibc source code is irrelevant really.
You could check the MinGW-w64 headers here if you want to see how they handle (ms_)wprintf: https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/tree/master/mingw-w64-headers

@rubenvb My quoted GCC docs page says: On MinGW targets, ms_printf, ms_scanf, and ms_strftime are also present.  Again, no mention of wchar_t support, e.g., ms_wprintf.  Here is the MinGW-W64 declaration of wprintf(): https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/blob/8bcd5fc1a72c0b6da3147bf21a4a494c81d14fae/mingw-w64-headers/crt/wchar.h#L525
